# Why am i getting the error NoReverseMatch at /?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a blogsite on django. I am a beginner and I don't know why am I getting this error.
Please help me solving this error. I am providing my code views.py, models.py, and base.html file

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        null = True
        )
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default='')
    text = models.TextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self): # new
        return reverse('blog_post_details', args=[str(self.id)])
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

from .models import Post

class HomeResponse(ListView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'home.html'

class PostDetail(DetailView):
    """docstring for PostDetail"""
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'



class NewPost(CreateView):
        model = Post
        template_name = 'new_post.html'
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is my code for urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomeResponse.as_view(), name='blog_name'),
    path('post/new/', views.NewPost.as_view(), name='blog_new_post'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/',views.PostDetail.as_view(),name='blog_post_details'),
]
```

base.html browser shows error for this code.It says `Reverse for 'blog_post_details' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Django Blog</h1>
        <h4 style="float: right;"><a href="{% url 'blog_new_post' %}">+ New Post</a></h4>
        <hr>
    </header>
    <a href="{% url 'blog_name' %}">Home</a>
    <a href="#"></a>

    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}

</body>
</html>


{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

This is the template with blog_post_details link
    {% block content %}

```
    {% for post in object_list %}

            <fieldset><a href="{% url 'blog_post_details' %}">
                <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
                <p style="font-size: 20px;">{{ post.text }}</p>
                <h4>By: {{ post.author }}</h4></a>
            </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: where is the template with blog post detail link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the id also in templates, detail view is specifically looking for an id to display the detail view which is mentioned in url and view but not in templates

```
<a href="{% url 'blog_post_details' post.id %}">
```